# .htaccess files removing CSS from Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

New to htaccess files and have spent a whole day trying to configure one by robbing snippets here and there but not really sure what is going on...

I'm trying to set up a Magento site and at first was getting only 500 errors, when I resolved that I was getting 404s in the middle of the main page and could not access the admin side at all, then just 404's on the admin page...

I eventually got this file where I am not getting any server errors but i'm not sure if it is what it should be, if I am not mistaking it is not allowing any image files to be displayed on the admin side, as it just looks like basic html and not an actual dashboard where I can start to configure things...

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

```
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting
    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

## default index file
    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
## adjust memory limit
    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized
    php_flag session.auto_start off
## enable resulting html compression
    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
## adjust memory limit
    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized
    php_flag session.auto_start off
## enable resulting html compression
    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip
# Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

    ##SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
    #RewriteBase /magento/
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
## redirect for mobile user agents
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>

## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0
</IfModule>

## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
    <Files composer.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTOR_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.html>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
    #FileETag none
## Add custom headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Tried adding RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(css|js|png|jpg)$ to this but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace .htaccess file with default one and then please check your server setting.

For Ubuntu edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` To edit this file run command

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**Modify from:**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Then restart apache**

sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

My advice, please always start with the logs, so enable debugging log level in httpd.conf/apache2.conf depends on what kind of distribution you are running, and search for the root cause in the log files, usually the defaults are /var/log/httpd/error.log & access.log (you can change the paths via variables in httpd.conf). You've blindly changed nobody knows what which is not a best solution I'd say. You should alway know what you're doing.